# Would this make sense?

Tags: motto

So soon I'm getting a tattoo to say live without regret. I've pottered around on the internet a bit and found

*Sine Paenitentia Vive* / *Vive sine Paenitentia* for this. I assume this is correct.

I also want to pair it with the all too cliché [Memento Mori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_mori), the previous line sitting above this. Would there be anything syntactically wrong with this? As two phrases? As a sentence with a break between them?

Answer (score 2):

You're very right to wonder about formatting the Latin language. The "truest" ancient formatting would be in all capital letters without spaces, i.e:

> MEMENTOMORI

and

> VIVESINEPAENITENTIA

It would be classically correct to separate these phrases by a line break. All that said however, I don't think it's necessary to stick with classical formattin. Spacing the letters will let the meanings be more recognizable to more people, which I think may be preferable to you?

In terms of lettering or fonts (I know you didn't ask about them specifically), there are some [graffiti in Pompeii which could make an interesting font](https://pompeiitourguide.me/2014/06/06/the-walls-of-pompeii-the-inscriptions-and-the-graffiti/).

Comment: That graffiti script is [(old) Roman cursive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_cursive), the usual script employed by the ancient Romans for handwriting on wax, papyrus and indeed walls. If I ever get me one of those Latin tattoos, it better be in Roman cursive ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Sine Paenitentia Vive

seems to be okay.

> Vive sine Paenitentia

on the other hand, should probably be "*vive sine **ulla** paenitentia*".

Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will point out if I am correct.

Comment: I think the "ulla" is specific, but I don't think it's necessary. On the one hand it would be "live without regret," and on the other it would be "live without any regret."